# js getting data from xml response.text()

Tags: javascript, json, xml, reactjs, xml-parsing

I'm making and ajax request to an API that sends back XML format. With the following code the responseXml data gets printed out, but I don't know how I can parse it and access the data (like item.line or item.origTime).

Should I use JSON parser somehow or something else?

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { schedules: [] };

    fetch('http://api.bart.gov/api/sched.aspx?cmd=stnsched&key=' + API_KEY + '&orig=12th&date=today')
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((responseXML) => {
        this.setState({schedules: responseXML});
        console.log(responseXML);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <SelectList />
        <TimeTable schedules={this.state.schedules} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

xml response

```
<root>
  <uri>...</uri>
  <date>7/22/2016</date>
  <sched_num>39</sched_num>
  <station>
    <name>12th St. Oakland City Center</name>
    <abbr>12TH</abbr>
    <item line="ROUTE 7" trainHeadStation="MLBR" origTime="4:36 AM" destTime="5:21 AM" trainIdx="1" bikeflag="1"/>
    <item line="ROUTE 2" trainHeadStation="PITT" origTime="4:37 AM" destTime="5:17 AM" trainIdx="1" bikeflag="1"/>
    <item line="ROUTE 3" trainHeadStation="RICH" origTime="4:37 AM" destTime="5:00 AM" trainIdx="1" bikeflag="1"/>
    <item line="ROUTE 1" trainHeadStation="SFIA" origTime="4:43 AM" destTime="5:28 AM" trainIdx="1" bikeflag="1"/>
    ......
```

Comment: jxon is what you need. https://github.com/tyrasd/jxon

Comment: Jiang, could you pls write a code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the code exmaple, check the console output:
https://jsfiddle.net/5rddp7tx/

```
const xmlStr=`
<root>
  <uri>...</uri>
  <date>7/22/2016</date>
  <sched_num>39</sched_num>
  <station>
    <name>12th St. Oakland City Center</name>
    <abbr>12TH</abbr>
    <item line="ROUTE 7" trainHeadStation="MLBR" origTime="4:36 AM" destTime="5:21 AM" trainIdx="1" bikeflag="1"/>
    <item line="ROUTE 2" trainHeadStation="PITT" origTime="4:37 AM" destTime="5:17 AM" trainIdx="1" bikeflag="1"/>
    <item line="ROUTE 3" trainHeadStation="RICH" origTime="4:37 AM" destTime="5:00 AM" trainIdx="1" bikeflag="1"/>
    <item line="ROUTE 1" trainHeadStation="SFIA" origTime="4:43 AM" destTime="5:28 AM" trainIdx="1" bikeflag="1"/>
  </station>
</root>
`
var myObject = JXON.build(JXON.stringToXml(xmlStr));
console.log(myObject);
console.log(myObject.root.station.item[2].$line);
```